# How to invoke Blob setter method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, object, blob, setter

I have a class with the following getter/setter:

```
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
```

I have a test method from where I need to invoke the blob setter from the controller class.

Please advise how to create in the test class an apex Blob object and how to pass the Blob object to the setter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below code in your test class:

```
String myString = 'field1,field2,field3';
Blob myBlob = Blob.valueof(myString);
MainClass obj = new MainClass();
obj.csvFileBody = myBlob;
```

You can also add custom setter method to assign value to your class variable. for e.g.

```
public void setCSVFileBody (Blob body) {
  this.csvFileBody = body;
}
```